# How to find times of my attendance at office?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

When I go to office, I turn my computer on or mostly resume it from stand-by and when going to return home turn it off or usually sleep it. During the day I sleep it too, mostly before going to meetings and resume it when I come back to work.
Is there any linux command (ubuntu 20.04) to list first resume or turn on and last sleep or turn off in days during the last month or more? I've tried `last /var/log/wtmp`, but it doesn't include some days I've been at office.

Comment: Though it might help your own timekeeping, an employer might question the data if you can log in remotely.

Comment: Not working remotely.